# Jersey not trapping injection exception

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, hk2, exceptionmapper

In my Jersey / JAX-RS resource I'm injecting a header param:

```
@Path("/foo")
class MyService {
    @HeaderParam("Authorization")
    public void setAuth(String auth) {
        if (!"mysecret".equals(auth)) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("nope");
        }
    }        
}
```

I register a NotAuthorizedExceptionMapper to handle the exception, and it works fine. It traps the exception, logs it the way I want, and then returns a Response object.

The problem is that Jersey / HK2 isn't ok with that. It insists on logging a full stack trace:

```
2019-07-02 15:24:09.330  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors 31850 WARN  The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.myproject.core.SecureService.setAuth(SecureService.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1264)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.methodMe(ClazzCreator.java:295)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:348)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
```

the rest of it, per the comment:

```
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: method inject on org.myproject.core.services.UserService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my exception mapper code:

```
    public static class NotAuthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotAuthorizedException> {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotAuthorizedException e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object o: e.getChallenges()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(o.toString());
        }
        String msgs = sb.toString();

        logger.error(e.getMessage() + " " + msgs);
        return Message.failureResponse(msgs, Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

HK2 should not do this. The exception has already been handled. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hmmm the internal exception is thrown/happens *before* the controllers global exception handler it seems. Also, it's logged at `WARN` level, so if possible you can rise level to ERROR for those packages.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz In the log file the global exception handler runs my log statement before the warning shows up.

Comment: Makes sense, what I meant is that the code throwing it is outside (before) in the code stack, might be why the custom handler is not avoiding it. Tricky wording lol.

Comment: I am pretty sure that hk2 isn't logging the exception itself.  Must be Jersey code

Comment: This isn't all of the stacktrace. Where's the caused by? And where's the exceptionmapper code?

Comment: @kolossus I added the rest of the stack trace and the exceptionmapper code. There isn't a "caused by" section -- this is all of it.

Comment: From the way this reads, it appears *two* exceptions occurred - your ExceptionMapper is handling only the one you're responsible for. While I can't tell for sure why the other IllegalStateException is happening, I'd say try adding a mapper for that and see how it goes @ccleve